What is this part marked WH5 33?
What is this part and what is its part number? I can't find a part with the code WH5 33.


D8 indicates that it may be a diode

it looks like some sort of dual diode, judging from the burn marks possibly a TVS

It's a Nexperia MMBZ27VAL TVS diode.


(Source: lcsc.com)

ok W means made in china H5 is the marking code what about 33 after it and if you sure this is it what is the common substitute for it if i couldn't find it
also mention the main and important characteristics please
thank you

as i returned to the datasheet you sent i found the maximum voltage is 22v while it works on 3d printer board (makerbot Mightyboard rev h) it uses 24v
is that means it will blow up after soldering it

@AhmadAbdElMaksoud 33 is some traceability code, like a lot number or similar. It's not important for identification. For your second question, why would you need a substitute? The diode is widely available. And lastly, the reverse standoff voltage is not the voltage the diode "blows up". Look at the figure 8 and 9 of the datasheet on page 11. It shows the diode's conduction behaviour at the different voltages.
